# Twitter bootstrap modal and date element

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have registration form with date element of HTML 5 (use for user b-date). 
Yes, it works find but, I see some problem.
If I choose month (e.g I choose month APRIL) the modal will close and the date element left.
Thank you so much.

I have this form:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="class" value="client" />
      <input type="hidden" name="func" value="add" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recordnumber">Record Number</label>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="record_number" name="record_number" placeholder="Enter Record Number" required>
      </div>                      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birthdate">Birth Date</label>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" id="date_birth" name="date_birth" placeholder="Enter Birth Date" required>
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="deathdate">Date of Death</label>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" style="z-index: 10520" class="form-control" id="date_death" name="date_death" placeholder="Enter Date of Death" required>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clinictype">Client Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="client_type" id="client_type" required>
          <option value="">Select Client Type</option>
            <?php 
            $_data = $type->get_all('client');
            if($_data!=false): foreach($_data['value'] as $data ): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data ?>"><?php echo $data ?></option>    
            <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
        </select>
      </div>                                                              
      <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-default">
    </form>
```

Comment: was this code copied directly? because i notice you have `type='text'` for both your birthday and date of death. and you talk about using HTML5 `type='date'`

Comment: yes, because there some JQuery code for that specific element. 
I also tried this:

    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="deathdate">Date of Death</label>
            <input type="date" style="z-index: 2051; !important;" class="form-control" id="date_death" name="date_death" placeholder="Enter Date of Death" required>
          </div> 

but still problem occur. I have read some forums and they suggeted to change the z-index: >= 10520 but, its still not working.

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: if you're going to use Jquery to create a date picker you're going to have to post that code as well. if you know your users will be using a browser with the `type='date'` available, i would suggest that. it works very well.